# Get list of files in Google Drive from PHP

Tags: php, google-api

I am tapping into Google Drive to get a list of files through my local PHP app.
Below is the code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key=AIzaSyAmWcZArf7NCk4d65HoKZzLENCJ6cx9fNg');
```

This throws the error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key=AIzaSyAmWcZArf7NCk4d65HoKZzLENCJ6cx9fNg):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in
>   D:\inetpub\wwwroot\ShabazTestPHP\googleDriveAPI.php on line 25

I have http, https and openssl wrappers enabled as I did a little test to print all the available wrappers:

```
array (size=11)
  0 => string 'php' (length=3)
  1 => string 'file' (length=4)
  2 => string 'glob' (length=4)
  3 => string 'data' (length=4)
  4 => string 'http' (length=4)
  5 => string 'ftp' (length=3)
  6 => string 'zip' (length=3)
  7 => string 'compress.zlib' (length=13)
  8 => string 'https' (length=5)
  9 => string 'ftps' (length=4)
  10 => string 'phar' (length=4)
```

Not sure what is going wrong here as I have everything set up and working fine.

I even tried wrapping my url into `url_encode()` but still get the same error.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm using Microsoft-IIS/7.5 and PHP version 5.6.0 if that helps.

Comment: Visit https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key=AIzaSyAmWcZArf7NCk4d65HoKZzLENCJ6cx9fNg in your browser, it will tell you that your API key has restrictions on it that prevent you from accessing the content.

Comment: I have set the HTTP Referrer requests for this API key so localhost should work with it? There are no restrictions.

Comment: localhost only works on the same machine. You are retrieving information from another machine, so to that machine localhost is itself, not you.

Comment: So how do I grant access to my local machine?

Comment: Go and Google "what is my IP" - then add that IP address to the list of permitted IP's

Comment: I have granted access to my IP address but still get the same error

Comment: Do I need the Google Client Library for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104446/discussion-between-the-avon-guy-and-user3574492).